# Fixed header wrong positioning

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question regarding my script. I have made a script that allows us to be able to make the header to stay in top of a users window when they scroll down on one of our pages. It does this for 5 seconds and than goes back to its original space in top of the page. There is only one problem, at the moment the header starts on top of other content but ends on the correct place. Does someone here know how to fix this? I think my problem is that I need the header to be fixed at the moment someone is scrolling down and when the countdown is still above zero. As soon as just one of these conditions is filled without the other the header still needs to be static. Does someone know how to make that possible. The result of my code at the moment is: 
http://scripts.semilo.com/mitchel/TEST_v14_multisize_LS.html

And the code itself:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
            /** * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) * http://cssreset.com */html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video {    margin: 0;  padding: 0; border: 0;  font-size: 100%;    font: inherit;  vertical-align: baseline;}/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {    display: block;}body {  line-height: 1;}ol, ul {    list-style: none;}blockquote, q {   quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after {   content: '';    content: none;}table {  border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;}

            header {
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 30px;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            background: #335C7D;
            color: #a3ff00;
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="myHeader">
        <h1>
             <div>
             <script src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
             googletag.pubads().definePassback('/4217/semilo.smulweb.nl', [[728, 90], [970, 250]]).setTargeting('campaign', [2017654321]).display();
             </script>
             </div>

             <div id="teller"; style="position:static; height:20px; width:100%; text-align:center; font-size: 14px; color:#a3ff00; font-style: sansita"> Deze ad verdwijnt in <span id="countdowntimer">5 </span> Seconden</div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            var timeleft = 5;
            var myHeader = document.getElementById('myHeader');
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            timeleft--;
            document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
            if(timeleft <= 0){
                myHeader.style.position = "static";
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                teller.style.display =  "none";   
            }
            },1000);
            </script>

        </h1>
    </header>

    <img src="http://scripts.semilo.com/mitchel/Weersverwachting.png" width="auto" height="auto" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's multiple options here. You could, for example, add empty space to the content's top and remove it after the 5 seconds. If not that, then you could change the `<img>`'s height and top.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timeleft = 5;
            var mySpace = document.getElementById('space');
            var myHeader = document.getElementById('header');
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
                timeleft--;
                document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
                if(timeleft <= 0){
                    document.getElementById("space").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").style.display = "none";
                    document.getElementById("header").style.position = "initial";
                    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                }
            },1000);
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: gray;
                height: 10%;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header" id="space"></div>
        <div class="header" id="header" style="position:fixed">
            <span id="countdowntimer">5</span>
        </div>
        <img src="http://scripts.semilo.com/mitchel/Weersverwachting.png" width="auto" height="auto">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit long but it does the trick, pick from it what you need (I think your question is really only related to the CSS part of it).

The banner is sticky for the first 5 seconds so if you scroll its comes with you, then slides up.

If you are already at the top the animation of sliding up doesn't happen.

Also the timer text disappears.

Hope this is helpful

```js
function Countdown(options) {
  var timer,
    instance = this,
    seconds = options.seconds || 10,
    updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function() {},
    counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function() {};

  function decrementCounter() {
    updateStatus(seconds);
    if (seconds === 0) {
      counterEnd();
      instance.stop();
    }
    seconds--;
  }

  this.start = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = 0;
    seconds = options.seconds;
    timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };
}

var myCounter = new Countdown({
  seconds: 5, // number of seconds to count down
  onUpdateStatus: function(sec) {
    $("#timer>span").html(sec);

  }, // callback for each second
  onCounterEnd: function() {
      if ($("body").scrollTop() > 0) {
        $(".banner").slideUp("fast", function() {
          $(".banner").removeClass("banner_sticky");
          $("#content").addClass("content_sticky");
          $("#timer").hide();
          $(".banner").slideDown("fast");
        });
      } else {
        $(".banner").removeClass("banner_sticky");
        $("#content").addClass("content_sticky");
        $("#timer").fadeOut("fast");
      }
    } // final action
});

myCounter.start();
```

```css
.banner {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner_sticky {
  position: fixed!important;
}

.content {
  height: 5000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner banner_sticky">
  <p id="timer">This banner will go to the top in <span>5</span></p>
</div>
<div class="content"><img src="http://scripts.semilo.com/mitchel/Weersverwachting.png" width="auto" height="auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had a better look at this and think i got the answer for you.

I wrapped the body of the page in

```
<div id="content">
  <img src="http://scripts.semilo.com/mitchel/Weersverwachting.png" width="auto" height="auto" />
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var downloadTimer = setInterval(function() {
timeleft--;
document.getElementById("countdowntimer").textContent = timeleft;
if (timeleft <= 0) {
  myHeader.style.position = "static";
  content.style.top = "0px";
  clearInterval(downloadTimer);
  teller.style.display = "none";
}
```

CSS

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #a3ff00;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  z-index:10;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k0b70uuu/